# Tell RMarkdown to not contain videos

Tags: html, r, markdown, r-markdown

RMarkdown is very useful and I build html documents containing both figures generated by R and some video links which I add straight through html as follows:

```
<video controls width="1000" height="600"  poster="linktoposter.jpg">
<source src="linkto.webm" type="video/webm">
<source src="http://linkto.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

This works absolutely fine except that RMarkdown downloads the video and embeds it in the html file.
When there are a few videos in the same document the html produced can reach 100s of megabytes in size.

I'd like to turn off the `self-contained` option but only for videos not for the charts R generates. Is there a way to do that? An html tag or class option perhaps?

Comment: By any chance did you resolve this? I am having the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Embed the video using iframe tag in html

```
---
title: "My video"
output: html_document
---

<iframe width="1000" height="600"
src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/XGSy3_Czz8k">
</iframe>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this won't work. I have a link to the raw videos but not to a hosting web-page. Also I like linking both a webm and an mp4 through html5. Nonetheless as a temporary measure I'll upload to youtube and hope the user doesn't mind too much.